# Animate Between Visibility Modes For Menu Item

Tags: android, animation, menu, visibility

I am trying to animate between the visibility mode for a menu.
By default all menu items are hidden but when the user clicks on the edit button i want to show all the items with an animation.

I have achieved the first part of changing the visibility of the menu items and that works fine but the animation part crashes the app.

Here is my code.

When user clicks on edit this is called.By default edit_mode is false.

```
if (!edit_mode) {
  edit_mode = true;
  supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
}
```

This is the menu code.

```
    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_add__custom, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    MenuItem photo = menu.findItem(R.id.photo);
    photo.setVisible(edit_mode);
    if (edit_mode)
        photo.getActionView().animate().alpha(1.0f);

    MenuItem date = menu.findItem(R.id.date);
    date.setVisible(edit_mode);
    if (edit_mode)
        date.getActionView().animate().alpha(1.0f);

    MenuItem done = menu.findItem(R.id.done);
    done.setVisible(edit_mode);
    if (edit_mode)
        done.getActionView().animate().alpha(1.0f);

    return edit_mode;
}
```

menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<item
    android:id="@+id/date"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_event_white_24dp"
    android:orderInCategory="200"
    android:title="Date"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/done"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_done_white_24dp"
    android:orderInCategory="300"
    android:title="Done"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/photo"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_photo_white_24dp"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="Done"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I sure that crash that you are having is there because of `NullException` thrown by `getActionView()`. First of all to animate that way you have set the actionView first during `onCreateOptionMenu()`. That way when you get the actionView in `onPrepareOptionsMenu` it wont crash because of that and then you can animate it. The `onPrepareOptionsMenu` executes when you press the menu button so your logic to animate it that time is correct.

If its just the text you want to show in menu item, it should go like this,

```
final MenuItem photo;

@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_my_report, menu);
        photo = menu.findItem(R.id.action1);
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setText("I am menu item");
        photo.setActionView(textView);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
if(someCondition)
{
        photo.getActionView().animate().alpha(1.0f);
}
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

In case you want to have the a complex and customise text you can set it using the layoutInflator service. This could go in your `onCreate`,

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        ImageView view = (ImageView)inflater.inflate(R.layout.some_view, null);
        Animation rotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade);
```

and `onCreateOptionMenu`,

```
view.startAnimation(rotation);
        photo.setActionView(view);
```

Its just to get you an idea what needed to be done, you can play around with this and can suit your need.

Comment: I have updated the question to show the menu.xml file.Each menu item is an icon and i am hiding and displaying icons,so do i still need to use textview or should i be using an imageview,if yes what all will i need to change?

Comment: you could use the image view for that, you can infalte and layout using layoutInflator service. See my answer above, this part is also explained. try to implement it